# How to match queries made by root from mysql slow queries log using regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's say I have a slow queries log like this:

```
# Time: 230706 17:12:48
# User@Host: sample[sample] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 626784  Schema: sample  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 2.976557  Lock_time: 0.000178  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 3344231
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 195
SET timestamp=1688677968;
SELECT * from a;

# Time: 230706 17:15:51
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 627770  Schema: sample  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 2.581676  Lock_time: 0.000270  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 2432228
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 195
SET timestamp=1688678151;
select * from cs;

# Time: 230706 17:13:37
# User@Host: sample[sample] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 627027  Schema: oiemorug_wp598  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 3.901325  Lock_time: 0.000145  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 3851050
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 195
SET timestamp=1688678017;
SELECT * from b

# Time: 230706 17:15:51
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 627770  Schema: sample  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 2.581676  Lock_time: 0.000270  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 2432228
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 195
SET timestamp=1688678151;
select * from cs
```

How can I match the full records where the query was done by the root user?
In this case it would be the second and the last records. (**User@Host: root[root]**)

I've tried several variations of these regex without too much success.

[This one](https://regex101.com/r/eQnJTs/1) `# Time.*?root.*?(?=# Time)` matches records not owned by the root user

[This one](https://regex101.com/r/kZrrkI/1) `# Time.*?root.*?(?!# Time)` doesn't match correctly

The main ideas is to remove all records owned by the root user from the slow query log.

Comment: You could use `/#.*?(\n{2}|$)/s` to get each record then use `strpos` to check for `root`; or you need 1 regex for all?

Comment: Non-regex answer? https://3v4l.org/bCi2E

Comment: Yes, if you can achieve this by _basic_ string comparison, then there is no point in having convoluted, unreadable regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

`# Time(?:(?!User@Host:)[\s\S])*?User@Host: (?'user'root)\[\k'user'\][\s\S]*?(?=(?:# Time|$))`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQnJTs/3)

Explanation:

1. Use a `negative lookahead` to assert that you don't match the pattern that points to the username: `(?!User@Host:)`
2. The whole thing is then made non-capturing: `(?:(?!User@Host:)[\s\S])*?`
3. Used a named capturing group for readability: `(?'user'root)`
4. Matched the username with the captured named group: `\[\k'user'\]`
5. The positive lookahead at the end uses the pipe (`|`) to assert either the start of the next record or the end of the record: `(?=(?:# Time|$))`

Answer (score 0):

In comments there was suggested literal string comparison without regex, which I support, so just search for raw string `# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []`

What else I could suggest to use `\s*` pattern instead of spaces to make sure whitespaces won't affect the output (`\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces).

Also I added `^` and `$` anchors to match start and end of a line respectively, so finally, the pattern I would suggest:

```
^#\s*User@Host:\s*root\[root\]\s*@\s*localhost\s*\[\]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYWiB5/1)